# Projection of circular motion on a perpendicular plane

Tags: geometry, dynamical-systems, projective-geometry, projective-space

First of all, I think the following question is more of a Mathematical question than physics question, so I am asking in math stackexchange.

Assume that a particle is rotating in $x$-$y$ plane about an axis ( call it $z$-axis) perpendicular to this plane. At any time, $t$, the $x$ and $y$ coordinate of the particle is written as:

\begin{equation}
x = a \sin(\omega t)\\
y = a \cos(\omega t)
\end{equation}

and the velocity of the particle is written as:

\begin{equation}
\dot{x} = a\omega \cos(\omega t)\\
\dot{y} = -a\omega \sin(\omega t)
\end{equation}

So, in $x$-$y$ plane the motion of the particle is represented by four parameters namely, $\dot{x},\dot{y},\omega, a$. I want to project this motion in $x$-$z$ plane (or $y$-$z$) plane to see if the motion of the particle can be represented by less number of parameters. Can anyone provide equation for the projection of this circular motion in the perpendicular plane.

Comment: it is just a sinusoidal motion along a segment

Comment: I understand that it will be an oscillatory motion along a line. But given the parameters in x-y plane how can we find the parameters in the perpendicular plane or vice-versa? and what is the exact equation describing this oscillatory motion?

Comment: It's unclear to me what you mean by "the motion of the particle is represented." Two of your parameters, $\omega$ and $a,$ are simple constants that control the scale of the motion, but they're only useful if you know the equations in the question; whereas if you know those equations, the values of the constants, and $t,$ you can obtain everything else. It's also puzzling that you ask for "motion" (rather than velocity) yet you do not list position (only velocity) among your "parameters."

Answer (score 0):

In the $x,z$ plane it will simply be
$$
\left\{ \matrix{
  x = a\sin \left( {\omega t} \right) \hfill \cr 
  z = 0 \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$

For other directions, put it vectorially
$$
{\bf r}(t) = \left( {x(t),y(t),z(t)} \right) = \left( {a\sin \left( {\omega t} \right),a\cos \left( {\omega t} \right),0} \right) = a\left( {\sin \left( {\omega t} \right),\cos \left( {\omega t} \right),0} \right)
$$
then take a unit vector $\bf n$ defining the direction of the segment into which
you want to project, and take the dot product to arrive to
$$
s(t) = a'\sin \left( {\omega t + \beta } \right) = a'\sin \left( {\omega \left( {t - t_0 } \right)} \right)
$$
where $a'=a$ if $\bf n$ is in the $x,y$ plane.